# How does memory management work on close modal dialog

Tags: qt

If I invoke the dialog this way:

```
void foo()
{
    QMessageBox* dlg = new QMessageBox( QMessageBox::Critical, "Error", "Unknown Error" );        
    dlg->exec();
}
```

Will the memory be freed after user have closed the dialog?

Please, point me to the appropriate doc, because I can’t find one.

Answer (score 2):

There's no single piece of documentation.

1. The `QMessageBox` is a `QObject`. It can be owned by a parent widget. It can also be deleted by the event loop when you call `deleteLater`.
2. Any top-level `QWidget` can have the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute set - it will self-delete when it gets closed.

In your case, since you're calling the (discouraged) blocking `exec()` method, you don't need to allocate the dialog on the heap. It could be an automatic variable:

```
QMessageBox dlg(QMessageBox::Critical, "Error", "Unknown Error");
dlg.exec();
```

Ideally, though, you should show the dialog and have it set up to delete itself upon closure:

```
QScopedPointer<QMessageBox> dlg(new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Critical, "Error", "Unknown Error"));
dlg->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
dlg.take()->show();
```

The smart pointer is used to prevent leaks in case the constructor were to fail, or if you changed the code later and there was a code path that missed `show()`. If the dialog is not shown, it would not ever be deleted - here, the smart pointer takes care of it. Either the dialog is shown, and deletes itself, or it is deleted by the pointer.

Comment: Why would you say that `exec()` is discouraged? Because of the local event loop it creates?

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I marked these as "right" because it the most informative. Of course I will use automatic variable.

Comment: @YuriyVelichko Calling `exec()` on an automatic instance is OK, but never do it on a non-modal dialog. Ideally, you should not call any `exec()` or `waitForXxx` (other than in `main()`).

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will leak the memory associated with `dlg`.

You want to change your code to be:

```
void foo()
{
    // Stack allocation is faster than heap allocation.
    // It also communicates the lifetime of the object better.
    QMessageBox dlg( QMessageBox::Critical, "Error", "Unknown Error" );        

    // This will block until the user closes the message.
    int result = dlg.exec();

} // dlg will be release upon losing scope here.
```

See [QMessageBox::exec](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#exec)

Answer (score 0):

Not by itself but you can connect `finished` to `deleteLater` and it will. Although creating a concrete instance on the stack like Matthew suggested is better